Postgres database missing in docker container using DBT
I'm following this data engineering course and I'm having trouble on the DBT part. I configured two databases, a source_db and a destination_db, using this docker-compose.yml file :
# version: '3'

services:
  source_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - elt_network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: source_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./source_db_init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  destination_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    networks:
      - elt_network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: destination_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
  
  elt_script:
    build:
      context: ./elt
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["python3", "elt_script.py"]
    networks:
      - elt_network
    depends_on:
      - source_postgres
      - destination_postgres

  dbt:
    image: ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-postgres:1.8.1
    command: 
      [
        "run",
        "--profiles-dir",
        "/root",
        "--project-dir",
        "/dbt"
      ]
    networks:
      - elt_network
    volumes:
      - ./custom_postgres:/dbt
      - ~/.dbt:/root
    depends_on:
      - elt_script
    environment:
      DBT_PROFILE: custom_postgres
      DBT_TARGET: dev

networks:
  elt_network:
    driver: bridge


When I used the command docker compose up I end up with this error in the docker logs:
2024-06-03 18:40:32 16:40:32  Running with dbt=1.8.1
2024-06-03 18:40:32 16:40:32  Registered adapter: postgres=1.8.1
2024-06-03 18:40:32 16:40:32  Found 4 models, 20 data tests, 3 sources, 413 macros
2024-06-03 18:40:32 16:40:32  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  1 of 4 START sql table model public.actors ..................................... [RUN]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  1 of 4 ERROR creating sql table model public.actors ............................ [ERROR in 0.10s]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  2 of 4 START sql table model public.film_actors ................................ [RUN]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  2 of 4 ERROR creating sql table model public.film_actors ....................... [ERROR in 0.06s]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  3 of 4 START sql table model public.films ...................................... [RUN]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  3 of 4 ERROR creating sql table model public.films ............................. [ERROR in 0.06s]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  4 of 4 SKIP relation public.film_ratings ....................................... [SKIP]
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  Finished running 4 table models in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.46 seconds (0.46s).
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  Completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings:
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33    Database Error in model actors (models/example/actors.sql)
2024-06-03 18:40:33   relation "public.actors" does not exist
2024-06-03 18:40:33   LINE 12:     SELECT * FROM "destination_db"."public"."actors"
2024-06-03 18:40:33                              ^
2024-06-03 18:40:33   compiled Code at target/run/custom_postgres/models/example/actors.sql
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33    Database Error in model film_actors (models/example/film_actors.sql)
2024-06-03 18:40:33   relation "public.film_actors" does not exist
2024-06-03 18:40:33   LINE 12:     SELECT * FROM "destination_db"."public"."film_actors"
2024-06-03 18:40:33                              ^
2024-06-03 18:40:33   compiled Code at target/run/custom_postgres/models/example/film_actors.sql
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33    Database Error in model films (models/example/films.sql)
2024-06-03 18:40:33   relation "public.films" does not exist
2024-06-03 18:40:33   LINE 12:     SELECT * FROM "destination_db"."public"."films"
2024-06-03 18:40:33                              ^
2024-06-03 18:40:33   compiled Code at target/run/custom_postgres/models/example/films.sql
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  
2024-06-03 18:40:33 16:40:33  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=3 SKIP=1 TOTAL=4


It's pointing that some relations does not exist but I investigated in the destination_db docker container doing so :
connect to container command line:
docker exec -it <id_of_my_container> bash
switch to the postgres user inside my container:
su - postgres
enable postgreSQL command line:
psql
connection to destination_db:
\c destination_db
list of tables inside destination_db:
\dt
All the tables listed in the error logs were here.
I don't understand what is going wrong.

That error tends to suggest you haven't run database migrations.  How would you run them in a non-Docker context?  You shouldn't normally need the docker exec debugging tool to interact with a database.

The database migration from source_db to destination_db is done by using the pg_dump command executed by the python script elt_script.py. So far, it's all I understood from the tutorial, I'm quite a newbie in data field
